Python Custom Programming Language, Yacc code inside a block, is being called
I have created a simple programming language for about 3 hours and so but i just can't fix that yacc keeps executing code inside a if block.
i've tried using lambdas, functions, external libraries but it made it worse so im giving the first version of the code that had the problem
this is the yacc functions i use
def t_error(t):
    print(f"unexpected token: {t.value}")
    sys.exit()

lexer = lex.lex()

variables = {}

def p_program(p):
    '''
    program : statements
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_statements(p):
    '''
    statements : statement
               | statement statements
    '''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = p[1]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_literals(p):
    '''
    expression : ID
              | INT
              | FLOAT
              | BOOL
              | STRING
    '''
    if p[1] in variables and isinstance(p[1], str):
        p[0] = variables[p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_cmp(p):
    '''
    expression : expression CMP expression
    '''
    if p[2] == "==":
        p[0] = p[1] == p[3]

def p_statement_assign(p):
    '''
    statement : ID EQ expression
    '''
    variables[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''
    expression : expression ADD expression
               | expression SUB expression
               | expression MUL expression
               | expression DIV expression
    '''
    if p[2] == "+":
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    elif p[2] == "-":
        p[0] = p[1] - p[3]
    elif p[2] == "*":
        p[0] = p[1] * p[3]
    elif p[2] == "/":
        p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_expression_group(p):
    '''
    expression : LP expression RP
               | LP statement RP
    '''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_scope_block(p):
    '''
    block : LCB statements RCB
    '''
    p[0] = p[2]
def c_print(arg):
    arg = str(arg)
    arg = arg.lstrip('"')
    arg = arg.rstrip('"')
    print(arg)
def p_print(p):
    '''
    statement : PRINT LP expression RP
    '''
    c_print(p[3])

def p_if_statement(p):
    '''
    statement : IF expression block
              | IF expression block ELSE block
    '''
    if p[2]:
        p[0] = p[3]
    elif len(p) == 6:  # for 'else' part
        p[0] = p[5]

def p_error(p):
    print("Syntax error at '%s'" % p.value)



parser = yacc.yacc()

parser.parse(code)


i haven't really delve to the depths of creating an interpreter and new to the topic.
when i do an if statement, the block is being called no matter the condition.

Your parser is immediately evaluating expressions instead of building a syntax tree. p_expression_binop, for example, should not actually be adding/subtracting/etc numbers, but building a data structure that represents arithmetic. Once you have the full syntax tree, you can pass that to an evaluator, which can "execute" your code, or pretty print it, or transform/optimize it, etc.

im using yacc which dont have the capability of making a syntax tree, you write grammar and yacc executes it.

i don't have sufficient understanding in parsing so i use grammar based libraries

Of course yacc can build a syntax tree. You just do something like p[0] = ('+', p[1], p[3]) instead of p[0] = p[1] + p[3]. An evaluation function evaluate(expr) would then do something like if expr[0] == '+': return evaluate(expr[1]) + evaluate(expr[2]).

"Executing" the parser just means parsing your code, not necessarily executing the semantics of your language.
